# How to change text in BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, baseadapter

I am trying to change the text of button inside `onClick()` but it's not changing. I have tried the following -

```
 viewHoder.btn_select_qq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               viewHoder.btn_select.setText("xxxxx");
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

How to set it?

Comment: A bit more of context/code would be helpful. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: do you want to change value on button click and retain it ?

Comment: @akshay_shahane yes, i want to change text in button when click

Comment: @HusaynHakeem I set this code in getView() and ViewHoder is final <--- it's problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
viewHoder.btn_select_qq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Button b = (Button) v;
               b.setText("xxxxx");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you edit comment not `v.setText` ,it's `b.setText`

Comment: Hey , I have some problem when I click more than 1 button ,a previous button is not setText

Comment: @ARR.s Sorry, i didn't get you. Can you explain what you did exactly ? Thanks :)

Comment: sorry , my english is not good, When i click `btn_select_qq` in first time  it's change text to "xxxx" but I click other `btn_select_qq` it's last `btn_select_qq` click is change but previous  `btn_select_qq` is not change(back to default)

Comment: @ARR.s That's fine. Can you upload the complete code :)

Comment: when i not remove  `notifyDataSetChanged();` it's not change text but I want to  `notifyDataSetChanged();` :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153053/discussion-between-sachin-aggarwal-and-arr-s).